# Proper way of testing directives

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, karma-runner, browserify

Let's say I've built very simple directive:

```
moment = require 'moment'   # as you can see I'm using browserify

###  whenever mouse hovered, it shows relative time ###
app.directive 'simpleDirective',->
   restrict: 'E'
   scope: date:'='
   template: "<div class='nice-date' date='date' ng-mouseenter='hover = true' 
                        ng-mouseleave='hover = false'>{{niceDate}}</div>"
   controller: ($scope)->
       $scope.$watch 'hover',->
          $scope.niceDate = if $scope.hover 
             moment($scope.date).fromNow()
          else ''
```

Now, I can easily test if directive properly compiles, using test like this:

```
describe 'simpleDirective test', ->
    $compile = $rootScope = undefined
    beforeEach module('myApp')

    beforeEach inject (_$compile_, _$rootScope_) ->
      $compile = _$compile_
      $rootScope = _$rootScope_

    it 'Replaces the element with the appropriate content', ->
        var element = $compile("<simple-directive date='mydate' />")($rootScope)
        $rootScope.$digest()
        expect(element.html()).toContain("class='nice-date'")
```

Now, how can I test the behavior of `mouseenter`? I mean first of all I have no idea how to get to the guts of the controller. And also I have no idea how to access `moment.js` from tests (I'm using karma with mocha).

Should I turn `moment.js` thing into ng-service dependency? Then it means every single thing used I'm gonna have to import as an angular service? Or maybe I just use browserify on my tests? Then every single spec file has to be browserified independently, because there's no single entry point for tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to add `moment.js` as a karma dependency in your configuration file (usually named karma.conf.js... at least for Node projects anyway). That way you'll have access to it from the tests. Second, this is how I would write the tests:

```
describe('simlpleDirective', function() {
  var $scope, $compile;
  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  beforeEach(inject($rootScope, _$compile_) {
    // Always create a new scope to prevent permanently dirtying the root scope for other tests
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $compile = _$compile_
  });

  it('Replaces element with content or something like that', function() {
    // Abstract the date so that you can test it later
    var date = new Date(),
      element;

    $scope.mydate = date;

    $scope.$apply(function() {
      element = $compile("<simple-directive date='mydate'></simple-directive>")($scope);
    });

    // You have full access to the compiled element here
    expect(element.find('.nice-date').text()).toBe('');

    // You also have access to $scope variables here
    expect($scope.niceDate).toBe('');

    // You should probably wrap the hover stuff in another test, but I'm being lazy here
    formattedDate = moment(date).fromNow();
    // Manually trigger the hover event
    element.find('.nice-date').triggerHandler('mouseenter');

    // Now check one or both again
    // $scope.$apply or $scope.$digest might be necessary here
    expect(element.find('.nice-date').text()).toBe(formattedDate);
    expect($scope.niceDate).toBe(formattedDate);
  });
});
```

Hopefully that helps. **NOTE** that this code has not been tested so it might need some tweaks to suit your needs.

**NOTE 2** I just noticed that I also wrote this test in Jasmine. Let me know if it's not easy enough to understand.

Comment: that's awesome Mike! Thanks a lot. I'll give it a try. Jasmine is not a problem. I just needed to see it in a big picture.